# Library to Perform Link-Layer Packet Modification

Tags: packet, data-link-layer, packet-mangling

Is there a library out there that will allow me to perform link-layer packet modification for both incoming and outgoing packets?

Basically I want to do some transformations to a packet (for eg. changing IP payload) based on incoming MAC address, IP address, port, etc.
I also want to be able to do the same thing for outgoing packets, i.e., modify packets before they leave the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if IPTables can do the kind of packet payload modification that I want to do.
The article linked in the 1st answer allows modification only at network layer, not at link layer.

Solution: [WinpkFilter](http://www.ntkernel.com/w&p.php?id=7)

Answer (score 0):

Windows or linux? for linux there's iptables which has extensive code. As for Windows, here's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FwHookDrv.aspx) that might help you.

Hope this helps.